# what other ways can I use to access my web form fields?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I currently use `@ModelAttribute ClassName className` to "cast" my webform into a class.

```
@RequestMapping("/SaveEventRegistration")
public ModelAndView saveEventRegistration(@ModelAttribute EventRegistration userEventRegistration) {
```

I'm just wondering if I really need to do this. for there is a generic `form` class that list all the fields in my web form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have access to the request:

```
@RequestMapping("/SaveEventRegistration")
public ModelAndView saveEventRegistration(HttpServletRequest request) {
```

And then get you form data manually using:

```
request.getParameter("fieldName");
```

Comment: thanks for the answer. Is this best practice though? just learning spring webmvc and finding out stuff. thanks again! :)

Comment: Not really a best practice but can be useful for forms that don't need binding (no need to create an object to hold form's data).